# Проблема с iconv() PHP

Tags: php, кодировка, перекодировка

Товарищи подскажите пожалуйста. Прихожу на некоторую страницу с запросом вида `index.php?gost=ГОСТ%C2%A0Р%C2%A050571.5.51−2013` вот код

```
$query = $_GET['gost'];
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
echo '1 '.$query.'<br>'; // ВИЖУ
$query = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', ' ', $query);
echo '2 '.$query.'<br>'; // ВИЖУ
$query = preg_replace('/\s+/','%',$query);
$query = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $query);
echo '3 '.$query; // ПУСТО
```

Пункт 3 пустой.

Однако если прихожу с запросом `index.php?gost=ГОСТ%C2%A0Р%20ИСО/МЭК%2074981-99`, то все 3 пункта отображаются нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас символ тире закодирован как-то криво в первом случае.
Он имеет ASCII-код отличный от 2D

Comment: strtr в данном случае лучше чем preg_replace.

Comment: Ага, а `str_replace` еще лучше.